# Opening foreign file extensions, like in game files, How is it done?

Tags: c#, assembly, lua, game-engine, reverse-engineering

In the sake of this game I'm modding at the moment, which has archives ending in ".rpf" (which is short for 'rage engine package file')

How exactly is it that programmers, can find  ways to open these types of files/archives, without having access to the rage engine?

What would one need to know in order to even begin trying to open a foreign file extension? The files can be opened thanks to the OpenIV Team who created the program necessary for opening the files, but how exactly does a developer, figure out or even know where to start when it comes to developing an application that is to fulfill the task of opening another file?

Comment: A web search brought this : http://www.gtamodding.com/wiki/RPF_archive

Comment: As said you have to look up the file format. Even for common types like `bmp` you won't get far unless you study its documentation. However, it's not "opening the file" which is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's called [Reverse engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering#Reverse_engineering_of_software)
You look into file with hex editor, notice some texts, or numbers that look like offsets. You apply your own experience writing similar stuff, make some assumptions and check if it is correct for multiple entries, and so on and so forth.

Comment: So would knowledge of assembly programming be particularly good to have in this area?

Comment: @JZersche not necessarily. Talk about hexadecimal data does not need assembler. It's a way of looking at or expressing data values. But as the answer says, knowing how to read hex data is valuable when exploring file formats. Hex representation is like a shorthand for the harder-to-read `binary` values, condensing sets of 4 bits into a format more easily readable by humans.

Answer (score 0):

There many ways to open such files.
First you can use specific programs to open them like OpenIV for RPF archive.
If you would try to Mod or write a cheat for example, most people disassemble the program or open them with a Hex-Editor.

Programs like HexEdit change the binary values of a program into hexadecimal numbers, for example the byte 10100101 into Hex 0xA5h (A5).

Another way is to disassemble the program. Programs like ollyDbg, IDA Pro or other disassemble the binary values into assembly-code. Now you're able to search for some offsets, adresses and texts and you can remove or edit them to let the program do what you want.

Some programs are able to generate a pseudocode to C or C# e.g. (.NET Reflector) which helps you to understand what the program do.

After you read for example some memory adresses and their offsets, you can change them in the disassemble program itself (JNZ (Jump if not Zero) to JMP (Jump) for example to jump directly in every case) and write these code on the executable or you can implement them in a own program which changes them or patch them.

That is the princip you looking up for to understand how the program does work and then you add some features of your own or write a complete new application to fulfill the task of opening any file. Like Vlad said thats simply called reverse engineering.